# Will adding redundant React Context Provider affect performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

in my app, we have 2 context providers let say `contextA` and `contextB`, and we allow user to set the value for each context. And we have 2 options to do this.

**1.** We just wrap all children in 2 context provider, if user doesnt set either provider, it fallback to its default value. Some example code like this:

```
   const ConfigProvider: FC<PropsWithChildren<ConfigProviderProps>> = props => {
       const { children, a, b } = props;

   return <ConfigContextA.Provider value={{ ...defaultContextA, ...a }}>
      <ConfigContextB.Provider {...defaultContextB, ...b}>{children}</ConfigContextB.Provider>
    </ConfigContextA.Provider>
   }
```

**2.** We write `if-else` branch to only wrap the provider if user passed as props:

```
   const ConfigProvider: FC<PropsWithChildren<ConfigProviderProps>> = props => {
       const { children, a, b } = props;

   if(a&b)
   {return <ConfigContextA.Provider value={{ ...defaultContextA, ...a }}>
      <ConfigContextB.Provider {...defaultContextB, ...b}>{children}</ConfigContextB.Provider>
    </ConfigContextA.Provider>}

    if(a) {return <ConfigContextA.Provider value={{ ...defaultContextA, ...a }}>
     {children}
    </ConfigContextA.Provider>}

    if(b) {return <ConfigContextB.Provider value={{ ...defaultContextB, ...b }}>
     {children}
    </ConfigContextB.Provider>}
   
   }
    return <>{children}</>}
```

If we follow **option 1**, then the code will much cleaner, there is no if-else logic, however, every children may be wrapped with **unnecessary context**.

If we follow **option 2**, children only be wrapped with corresponding provider, however the apps need to run **additional if-else** branching logic.

Note that the context value is rarely be re-configured on runtime ( some value like `locale`)

So my question is between these 2 options, **which one is better in performance and memory cost?** thanks

Comment: Could explain what your trying to achieve? I feel this would be easier to answer and provide feedback if we knew your motives.

Comment: @KyleLambert hi, so basically, we are trying to build a UI library. Each component (children) will get value from contextA and contextB to render correspondingly ( for example `locale` information for correct text translation)

Comment: Don't worry about that, you can use useMemo and memo to memorize and avoid rerender unnecessarily. React is so smart, and it's just only rerendered what's changed